# The meaning of `split(%r{\s*})`

Tags: ruby, regex

`split(%r{\s*})` splits each letter ignoring spaces as in:

```
"hi mom".split(%r{\s*}) # => ["h", "i", "m", "o", "m"]
```

Why can `%r{\s*}` work this way?

Comment: Executing `%r{\s*}` returns `/\s*/`. Does that make it more clear? This is one of Ruby's [percent strings](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html). (Search "percent strings".)

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.  What confuses you about how this code works?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#comment17104_253896

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%r{...}` (or `%r[...]`, or `%r#....#`, or `%rX...X`... you get the gist) is equivalent to `/.../`, a RegExp literal. In a regular expression, `\s` is a space, and `*` is 0 or more of preceding token: together, the expression says "split the string at every point there is zero or more spaces". There is zero or more spaces between each character of the string (aside from the space, which gets swallowed as the recognised delimiter).

Answer (score 1):

`%r{\s*}` matches an arbitrary zero width position or one or more spaces, which are excluded from the result of the split.